# Spyder3 is crashing in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, spyder

My spyder 3 is crashing when it is initiated. I tried to uninstall and install again, but it didn't solve the problem:

```
sudo apt remove  spyder3
sudo apt-get install spyder3
```

I am not sure if the problem started when I installed Jupiter in my computer. Anyway, I also removed Jupyter and the problem persists:

```
ProblemType: Crash
CrashCounter: 1
CurrentDesktop: Unity
Date: Sun Jul 15 09:32:04 2018
ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/spyder3
ExecutableTimestamp: 1455634443
InterpreterPath: /usr/bin/python3.5
ProcCmdline: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/spyder3
ProcCwd: /home/daniel
ProcEnviron:
 PATH=(custom, user)
 SHELL=/bin/bash
 LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
 LANGUAGE=pt_BR:pt:en
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set>
```

Can you one suggest me how to solve this?

Comment: Did you [remove older dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/a/100953/751635) after uninstall? Also, try using pip to install [spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html) as link indicates the Ubuntu package *could be slightly outdated.* Do note: Ubuntu 16.04 comes shipped with python 2.7 which you need to use python3 for Spyder3 (i.e., `pip3 install spyder`).

Comment: Yes, I tried this but the problem still persists.

Comment: Is there a way to clean the python3 install to the default one?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *clean* but for ubuntu you would need both python 2 and 3.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please download and install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux) (which comes with Spyder) instead of the packages provided by your Linux distribution. They are usually very outdated, so we can't help you with errors in them. If after that the problem persists, then you need to run in a system terminal (e.g. xterm): `conda install pyopengl`. If you're unwilling to use Anaconda, you're basically on your own because we don't have the resources nor the time to give support to installations other than Anaconda.

Comment: Thanks @CarlosCordoba I didnt know about that. I have been using it for while without problems. Just now I have had problems with it.

Comment: @Parfait since the spyder were working ultil yesterday, I thought that something had happened with my installation in python and if I could return it to the python3 that comes with Ubuntu 16, my problem could be solved.